# Recognizing files with an application

Tags: c++, windows, qt, setup-deployment, file-extension

After I save a file in a folder with correct extension, when I go back and look at it, the file is unrecognizable to the application. The file association appears to be lost.

I want Windows to be able to recognize all files with a particular extension (*.sp) with my application. How do I do that? and How do I implement that in my VS deployment project.

Comment: You are creating desktop application with Qt? You have to write a key and value inside of it in the registry using QSettings in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT. The key should be named .sp immediately in Root key.
After this you have to set the (default) value to path where you executable should be installed followed by %1 for the first arg, which would be passed by explorer (the file selected by user) - this is valid for XP, but for Vista and Windows 7 not sure - I think there is a bit difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Deployment and Associations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91w8k8ea%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

The link includes this text:

> The deployment tools in Visual Studio include a File Types Editor,
>   which allows you to specify document types and associate them with
>   file extensions. In addition, you can specify the verbs or actions for
>   each document type and specify MIME types for the document types for
>   use in browsers. For more information, ...

So, I guess it's exactly what you need. HTH

Comment: Hey.. Thanks!! I did this but whenever I click on the file, it launches the application, but doesnt open the file itself. Anything I m missing on?

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.qt.nokia.com/wiki/Assigning_a_file_type_to_an_Application_on_Windows